# Getting error "The required field Extension is missing from the input structure." when trying to update a report datasource using SSRS Rest API

Tags: sql-server, rest, api, reporting-services, report

I am trying to update an existing report to use a shared datasource using the SSRS Rest Api v2. I am getting the error back "The required field Extension is missing from the input structure." Error code 1008. I have not been able to figure out what needs to be in the request. I have tried the examples in the api documentation to no avail. Has anybody experience this? Below is the request I am sending.

URL: http://reportserver/reports/api/v2.0/reports({reportid})/DataSources
Method: PUT
Json data:
[{"Id":"4252a76c-3117-4c33-a4ce-361c3dfcc602", "Name":"DataSource1","Path":"/Test/Data Sources","Type":"DataSource","IsReference":false}]

I understand it is looking for something in the payload but I can not figure out what is missing. "Extension" isn't a field listed in the api documentation.